# The value of the array size variable changes without me expicitly changing it in my c++ merge sort code

Tags: c++, arrays

The value of the size variable changes to 32760 without me explicitly changing it in my C++ Merge Sort code.
I have shared my code below. The size value is 3 before calling merge sort function but it becomes 32760 after merge sort gets completed.

```
# include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void printarr(int *arr,int size);
void merge(int *arr,int l,int m,int r)
{
    int temp[100];
    int k=0,i=l,j=m+1;
    while(i<=m && j<=r)
    {
        if(arr[i]<arr[j])
        {
            temp[k++]=arr[i++];
        }
        else
            temp[k++]=arr[j++];
    }
    while(i<=m)
    {
        temp[k++]=arr[i++];
    }
    while(j<=r)
    {
        temp[k++]=arr[j++];
    }
    for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
    {
        arr[l+i]=temp[i];
    }
}
void mergeSort(int *arr,int l,int r)
{
    if(l>=r)
    {
        return;
    }
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    mergeSort(arr,l,m);
    cout<<"left part sorted: \n";
    mergeSort(arr,m+1,r);
    cout<<"right part sorted: \n";
    merge(arr,l,m,r);
}
void printarr(int *arr,int size)
{
    cout<<"\nsize in printarr"<<size<<"\n"; 
    /*for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<"arr element "<<i<<" is "<<arr[i]<<"\n";
    }*/
}
int main()
{
    int arr[]={43,2,3};
    int size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout<<"size is "<<size<<"\n";
    mergeSort(arr,0,size-1);
    cout<<"\nmerge sort complete\n";
    cout<<"\n size in main "<<size<<"\n";
    printarr(arr,size);
}
```

[image: Output image]

Comment: In this case, I would look for out-of-bound writing. I guess something in `mergeSort()` writes to the address of a non-existing array element which accidentally is just the address of your `size` variable in `main()`.

Comment: As Scheff says you are acidentally writing outside the bounds of one of your arrays. Use a debugger to find out where the problem occurs.

Comment: As a side note, the conventional half-open ranges are conventional because they're easier to work with than closed ranges. Once you get used to them, many off-by-one errors just disappear.

Comment: Looks like `for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i < k; i++)`. Can't be 100% certain, though.

Comment: Related, mergesort (indeed most partitioning sort algorithms) are easier to implement if you let the *language* do the pointer math for you. In doing so your merge function only needs a base address, a mid point, and and overall length, and your mergesort function needs just a base address and a length. The rest is handled by pointer arithmetic. [See here](https://ideone.com/aZR0Mo). The implementation notwithstanding, note the pointer arithmetic in the mergesort function; that's what I'm referring to. Anyway, GL.

Comment: Thank you everyone! especially Adrian! Adrian's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian suggested, replacing for (i = 0; i <= k; i++) with for (i = 0; i < k; i++) rectifies the error. The k++ in while(i<=m) and while(j<=r) makes the value of k equal to the size of the temp array. Hence, while copying elements of temp array to arr array i<size_of_temp i.e i<k should be used.